# ¿Por qué atomic() no me funciona correctamente?

Tags: python, django

```py
with transaction.atomic():
    purchase = Purchases.objects.create()
    for item in json.loads(products):
        PurcharseDetail.objects.create()
        product = Product.objects.get(id=item['id'])
        product.stock += int(item['amount'])
        product.save()
```

Cuando ocurre un error dentro del bucle for, el resultado que espero es que se revierta purchase, pero esto no ocurre. Sin importar el error siempre se ejecuta purchase.